# c Warning[Pe188]: enumerated type mixed with another type

Tags: c, warnings

I got the warning:

> Warning[Pe188]: enumerated type mixed with another type

at:

```
ErrorFlag = (CurrentTime - TimerX > TIMEOUT_X);
```

but the warning is gone if I replace it with:

```
if(CurrentTime - TimerX > TIMEOUT_X)
{
  ErrorFlag = TRUE;
}
```

Whats wrong with the first method to set `ErrorFlag`?

**Edit**:

I have a local `enum`:

```
typedef enum{
   FALSE = 0;
   TRUE= 1;
}BOOL;
```

and `ErrorFlag` is of type `BOOL`.

Comment: Don't use some homebrew boolean! Use the standard `_Bool` resp. `bool` type and the macros in `stdbool.h`! And provide a [mcve]! Currently, it looks like you try compiling C code with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `C11`, chapter §6.5.8 (*emphasis mine*)

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=`
>   (greater than or equal to) shall **yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is
>   false.<sup>107)</sup> The result has type `int`.**

Which *may not* be the same type as `TRUE`, which seems to be an `enum` value local to your code.

Comment: yes, correct. But is there any way to set an enum using its element values, i.e. 0 as `FALSE` and 1 as `TRUE` in my case. Maybe something like `BOOL(0)` for `FALSE`?

Comment: _enum constants_ **are** `int`.

Comment: @user694733: Both are bad advice!

Comment: @Olaf Sorry sir if I'm missing something here, but I believed `enum`s are different type than plain old `int`, are they not?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Not in C (see my other comment)! http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3 That's why we should insist on a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf Right sir, just after that, P4, also says, _"The choice of type is implementation-defined,"_ so, there's no guarantee that the `enum` and `int` are compatible types, right?

Comment: @Olaf I was thinking of more general case, but you are right: using `stdbool.h` is better in this case. Comment removed.

Comment: Right the first sentence from p4: "Each enumerated type **shall be compatible** with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type".

Comment: @Olaf That's the point sir, implementation is free to choose, there's no guarantee of compatibility, right?

Comment: Read the bold part and check out the definition of "shall"! Anyway, that's one of the problems with homebrew boolean pseudo-types. They should jkust be banned and compilers should generate a hard error for `BOOL`, `Bool`, etc. `bool` should have been made a keyword, not that stupid `_Bool`. Interestingly the standard already reserves `bool` for future internal use. But snails are faster than the C commitee making C better and more consistent.

Comment: Yes, implementation may choose the type. Type of `TRUE` is irrelevant in the expression, only type of `ErrorFlag` matters, which (assuming IAR) is likely some 8-bit type.

Comment: @user694733: The problem is the missing mcve and detailed information. In fact the question should be closed for that missing. Apparently OP is not interested in enhancing his coding skills anyway.